# Как поднять два aiohttp сервера

Tags: python, aiohttp

Мне для авто-тестов требуется поднять два сервера. Использую aiohttp. С одним всё ок, как запустить два не понимаю. Подскажите, пожалуйста!

Answer (score 2):

Для запуска двух экземпляров сервера достаточно указать разные порты при выполнении `run_app`

```py
# app1.py
web.run_app(app, port='8080') #для первого

# app2.py
web.run_app(app, port='8081') #для второго
```

Соответственно запускать в разных окнах консоли / терминала, и в браузере указывать соответствующие адреса

Comment: Да, спасибо, это понятно. Но мне нужно из одного приложения запустить.

Comment: Процессы, потоки?

Comment: в авто-тесте мне нужно уметь сделать так:

server1.start(localhost, 8081)
server2.start(localhost, 8082)